# Tkinter Frame won't fill remaining space

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am just trying to make the green frame fill the remaining empty space of a window, but I can only get it to fill the bottom half no matter what I do.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoCfa.png)

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class CredsWindow:

    def __init__(self, root):

        root.title("Greenbox")
        root.geometry("300x200")
        root.attributes('-topmost', True)

        self.drag_offsetx = IntVar()
        self.drag_offsety = IntVar()

        def drag_window_start(v):
            self.drag_offsetx = v.x
            self.drag_offsety = v.y

        def drag_window(v):
            x = root.winfo_pointerx()-self.drag_offsetx
            y = root.winfo_pointery()-self.drag_offsety
            root.geometry(f'+{x}+{y}')

        title_bar = Frame(root, bg="#252525")
        title_bar.pack(anchor=N, expand=True, fill=X)
        title_bar.bind("<Button-1>", drag_window_start)
        title_bar.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_window)

        title_label = Label(title_bar, text="Greenbox", bg="#252525", fg="white")
        title_label.pack(side=LEFT, pady=3, padx=2)

        close_button = Button(title_bar, text="X", bg="#252525", fg="white", relief="flat", command=root.quit)
        close_button.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=3, padx=2)

        
        mainframe = Frame(root, bg='#171717')
        mainframe.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)


root = Tk()
CredsWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `expand=True` in this statement:

```
title_bar.pack(anchor=N, expand=True, fill=X)
```

When you set it to `True`, you're telling `pack` to have it allocate extra space to that widget. You've also added `expand=True` when packing `mainframe`, which means that all unused space will be evenly distributed between `title_bar` and `mainframe`.